# Dell PowerVault 122T change from Sequential Mode to Random mode - how?

Tags: dell, dell-powervault

I have 4 PowerVault 122T tape drives.  Three of them say SEQ on the front lcd screen.  One does not.

I'm using Backup Exec 2010 R3 to restore data from old tapes.  I have 2 tape drives connected to a Dell PowerEdge 2600 and the other 2 connected to a PowerEdge 2850 (both servers are Win 2003 STD x86)

The one tape drive that does not have SEQ on the front lcd screen actually works.  It shows up as a medium change in the device manager.  I'm able to inventory, catalog, and restore backed up data.  I'm attributing this to the tape drive NOT having SEQ on the front lcd screen, because I believe the tape drive is in random mode.  Which is what I'm trying to my other 3 drives into.  Iv'e read online and the user manual for the tape drives that the SEQ means they are in sequential mode.  However, while they are in sequential mode, they will not show up as a medium change in the Windows device manager.  if I can't get as a medium changer, backup exec won't recognize them as robotic libraries.  So, I'm kind of stuck here.

My one tape drive that does work.  No idea how it got into random mode.  Just came like that really.  I just plugged it in, turned it on and everything just worked.  My situation now is...How do I get my three other drives to go from sequential to random?

Thanks